# Page locking Disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are running a maintenance job contains the job of re-orgnizing indexes. When it reach to a certain index it will fail with the message "Cannot be reorgnized because page level locking is disabled".

My question is, can we change this setting without referring back to application owner/vendor? Please advise.

Comment: That depends on your application owner / vendor!. Do you have an internal DBA? Have you googled this to understand what it is?

Comment: Yes we did. As we understood the page locking by default is enabled. Disabling it will limit the type of locking in the object. The recommendation is to have all these options enabled but i need to know if we should go ahead and do the changes or consult the product owner first?

Comment: So who changed the defaults? was it the product owner or your DBA? I'm guessing you don't have a DBA and the product owner made this change for a reason. Non one can answer this questoin. It depends whether there is a supporrisk or not and this is not clear from the information provided

Comment: @Nick.Mcdemaid Thank you. Yes i guess its the product owner. We will check with them and get a clarification from the side. Thanks alot.